# Impedance matching - amplifier and surface acoustic wave (SAW) filter

Tags: amplifier, filter, impedance-matching, microwave

How would I properly do impedance matching for the amplifier and saw filter at the output of the circuit?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you mean "energy" rather than "impedance?"

Comment: yes sorry I meant impedance

Comment: Then edit the question and fix the wording.

Comment: already corrected

Comment: What impedance value are you trying to match to what drive source impedance and at what particular frequency?

Comment: I am trying to match the 50ohm impedance value to the 2.45ghz frequency. about drive source impedance It if the output impedance?I am using the HMC414 amplifier. The output is also 50 ohm impedance.

Comment: Then it is already matched!!!

Comment: My advisor told me that this 2.45 GHz point should be in the middle of the Smith chart. How to do it?